# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty [comments]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In short, I've just migrated a comments scaffold to the app. The goal is to have comments displayed in the show action of a song. It's simple, I have a songs model, a comments model, and a user model. The user can upload songs -- and I'd like the user to be able to add comments to the songs. Unfortunately, I've been hit with the below error. I've looked into various solutions to no avail.

**error msg:**

```
ArgumentError in Songs#show

Showing /Users/apane/Downloads/leap/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h2>
```

See the github below -- I feel this is the most efficient way for troubleshooting as it's pretty easy to browse to the appropriate directories quickly.

www.github.com/apane/leap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are showing this form in show action of songs controller, and it has to be like this:

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

Or in your form

`<%= form_for Comment.new do |f| %>`

Comment: By the way, your app uses rails 4, so you should tag your questions with rails 4. Soemtimes this makes it easier to debug an issue.

Comment: Will `Comment.new` hardcoded into the form not remove the ability to send back a comment with errors and populate the form?

Comment: @Damien I think no, because on submit comment is sent over to create action and in create action there is again a comment variable initiated and it calls errors on this one.